# combining 1) polymorphic many-to-many and 2) 3-way pivot?

Tags: laravel

I have a 3-way [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) pivot relationship for e.g. Movie, Person, Job. E.g. Kevin Costner is both actor and director in Dances With Wolves.

```
$movie->people()->attach($person, ['job_id'=> $job-id]);
```

I also have a [polymorphic many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) for tags. These tags can be applied to e.g. Movie.

```
$movie->tags()->attach($tag);
```

How can I combine the two? This so I can apply the Tag "Academy Award" not only to the Movie Dances With Wolves but also to Kevin Costner's acting in that movie.

Note: Movie has migration and model, job-movie-person is a migration only

```
// migrations

job
- id
- name // actor, director, etc.

person
- id
- name

movie
- id
- name

job-movie-person
- movie_id - foreignId
- person_id - foreignId
- job_id - foreignId


// Tag: straight from Laravel documentation
tag
- id
- name

taggables
- taggable_type // e.g. App\Models\Movie
- taggable_id
- tag_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would just tag movies.
Then I would get each person's tags via his movies' tags.

Comment: What do you mean with "get each person's tags via his movies' tags"? I need to define somewhere that Kevin Costner got an award for his acting job.